# iptables xt_recent change in kernel without modules

Tags: iptables, kernel

is it possible to change xt_recent module parameters when it is compiled into kernel ?

most of the info on internet suggest setting it by modprobe but that is not the case in my setup as I have kernel without module support

Comment: it is possible by adding it to kernel parameters at start (in grub.conf or lilo). for example: xt_recent.ip_list_tot=100